# "Esqueletonizar" figuras

Tags: c++, processamento-de-imagens

Escrevi um código para "esqueletonizar" figuras, isto é, para reduzir suas espessuras a apenas um pixel. Já havia escrito o código em Python que funcionou corretamente. Porém, o mesmo código reescrito para C++, embora compile e execute sem erros,não produz o mesmo resultado que o obtido com o uso de Python. Segue um trecho do código em C++  para ver se alguém me ajude, obrigado.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int vizinhos(int x, int y, int img[][180]);
int zero_um(int x, int y, int img[][180]);
int multiplica_r1(int x, int y, int img[][180]);
int multiplica_r2(int x, int y, int img[][180]);
int conta_pixels(int img[][180]);

// INÍCIO DA FUNÇÃO PRINCIPAL ******************************************
int main(){

    // Lê a imagem original
    Mat img;
    img = imread("/home/dexter/Público/xis.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    // Binariza a imagem
    Mat img_bin;
    threshold(img, img_bin, 50, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    // Obtém o negativo da imagem binarizada
    int img_bin_neg[180][180];
    for (int i=0; i<180; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<180; j++) {
            img_bin_neg[i][j] = (255 - img_bin.at<uchar>(i,j)) / 255;
        }
    }

    // EFETUA A ESQUELETONIZAÇÃO **************

    int brancos0, brancos1, dif;
    brancos0 = conta_pixels(img_bin_neg);
    dif = 10;
    int flag[180][180];

    while (dif > 0) {

        // Aplica conjunto de regras 1
        for (int i=1; i<179; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<179; j++) {

                int B = vizinhos(i,j,img_bin_neg);
                bool teste1 = (B >= 2) && (B <= 6);

                int A = zero_um(i,j,img_bin_neg);
                bool teste2 = (A == 1);

                int p2p4p6, p4p6p8 = multiplica_r1(i,j,img_bin_neg);
                bool teste3 = (p2p4p6 == 0);
                bool teste4 = (p4p6p8 == 0);

                if (teste1 * teste2 * teste3 * teste4 == 1) {
                    flag[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<180; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<180; j++) {
                if (flag[i][j] == 1) { img_bin_neg[i][j] = 0; }
            }
        }

        // Aplica conjunto de regras 2
        for (int i=1; i<179; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<179; j++) {

                int B = vizinhos(i,j,img_bin_neg);
                bool teste1A = (B >= 3) && (B <= 6);

                int A = zero_um(i,j,img_bin_neg);
                bool teste2A = (A == 1);

                int p2p4p8, p2p6p8 = multiplica_r2(i,j,img_bin_neg);
                bool teste3A = (p2p4p8 == 0);
                bool teste4A = (p2p6p8 == 0);

                if (teste1A * teste2A * teste3A * teste4A == 1) {
                    flag[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<180; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<180; j++) {
                if (flag[i][j] == 1) { img_bin_neg[i][j] = 0; }
            }
        }

        brancos1 = conta_pixels(img_bin_neg);
        dif = brancos0 - brancos1;
        brancos0 = brancos1;

    } // Fim do laço while


    // IMAGEM ESQUELETONIZADA
    int m_esqueleto[180][180];
    for (int i=0; i<180; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<180; j++) {
            m_esqueleto[i][j] = 1 - img_bin_neg[i][j];
        }
    }

    Mat esqueletonizada(180, 180, CV_8UC1);
    for (int i=0; i<180; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<180; j++) {
            esqueletonizada.at<uchar>(i,j) = m_esqueleto[i][j] * 255;
        }
    }

    namedWindow("img esqueletonizada", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("img esqueletonizada", esqueletonizada);
    waitKey();

return 0;
}   

// FIM DA FUNÇÃO PRINCIPAL *************************

// FUNÇÕES PARA ESQUELETONIZAÇÃO
int vizinhos(int x, int y, int img[][180]){
    int B = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        int v = j+y-1;
        B += img[x-1][v] + img[x+1][v];
    }
    B += img[x][y-1] + img[x][y+1];
    return B;
}

int zero_um(int x, int y, int img[][180]){
    int A = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        int v = j+y-1;
        if (img[x-1][v]==0 && img[x-1][v+1]==1) { A += 1; }
        if (img[x+1][v]==1 && img[x+1][v+1]==0) { A += 1; }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        int u = i+x-1;
        if (img[u][y+1]==0 && img[u+1][y+1]==1) { A += 1; }
        if (img[u][y-1]==1 && img[u+1][y-1]==0) { A += 1; }
    }
    return A;
}

int multiplica_r1(int x, int y, int img[][180]){
    int p2p4p6 = img[x-1][y] * img[x][y+1] * img[x+1][y];
    int p4p6p8 = img[x][y+1] * img[x+1][y] * img[x][y-1];
    return p2p4p6, p4p6p8;
}

int multiplica_r2(int x, int y, int img[][180]){
    int p2p4p8 = img[x-1][y] * img[x][y+1] * img[x][y-1];
    int p2p6p8 = img[x-1][y] * img[x+1][y] * img[x][y-1];
    return p2p4p8, p2p6p8;
}

int conta_pixels(int img[][180]){
    int pixels_brancos = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<180; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<180; j++){
            if (img[i][j] == 1) { pixels_brancos += 1; }
        }
    }
    return pixels_brancos;
}
```

Comment: Olá @Dexter, você esta querendo usar as funções do opencv mesmo para fazer isso, ou você está tentando fazer a "esqueletização" da sua própria maneira?

Comment: Usei opencv só para ler e manipular matrizes. Por falar nisso, nem sei se precisava importar todas essas bibliotecas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que você queria, mas pode ser que isso te ajude a chegar no que você espera, esse foi o resultado:

[image: imagem descrevendo o processo de preparação da imagem para a aplicação do thinning]

A abordagem que eu segui foi a cada passo realizado, gerar uma imagem para que eu pudesse entender o que estava acontecendo, depois da imagem lida em escala de cinza eu "separei" o que pra mim é "informação" no caso dessa imagem, apenas o logo sem o fundo cinza, e ai apliquei dois tipos de "esqueletização" (na documentação é referido como `thinning`), o primeiro é o `ZHANGSUEN` quarta imagem da esquerda para a direita, e o segundo o `GUOHALL` a quinta imagem, segue a documentação da [image: função] e dos tipos de [image: thinning].

Abaixo o código para demonstrar como foi feito todo o processo:

```
//Compila no linux com: g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` main.cpp -o thinning

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ximgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void gray_to_black( Mat& img );

int main(){

    Mat stack;
    Mat img_thinning_a;
    Mat img_thinning_b;
    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back( cv::ImwriteFlags::IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION );
    compression_params.push_back( 9 );

    //Obtém a imagem em escala de cinza
    stack = imread("/home/SOpt/Q376812/resources/SO_icon.png", cv::ImreadModes::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );        
    imwrite( "/home/SOpt/Q376812/resources/SO_gray.png", stack, compression_params );

    //identifica os pixels "acinzentados" e os define como preto (para o caso do logo)
    gray_to_black( stack );
    imwrite( "/home/SOpt/Q376812/resources/SO_gray_removed.png", stack, compression_params );

    //Aplica o Thinning de dois tipos diferentes
    ximgproc::thinning( stack, img_thinning_a, ximgproc::ThinningTypes::THINNING_ZHANGSUEN );
    ximgproc::thinning( stack, img_thinning_b, ximgproc::ThinningTypes::THINNING_GUOHALL );

    imwrite( "/home/SOpt/Q376812/resources/SO_thinning_a.png", img_thinning_a, compression_params );
    imwrite( "/home/SOpt/Q376812/resources/SO_thinning_b.png", img_thinning_b, compression_params );

    return 0;
}   

void gray_to_black( Mat& img )
{
    auto color = img.at<uchar>( 0, 0 );
    for( auto x = 0; x < img.rows; x++ )
    {
        for( int y = 0; y < img.cols; y++ )
        {
            color = img.at<uchar>( x, y );
            if( color != 0 && color != 255 )
            { 
                img.at<uchar>( x, y ) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maravilha, funcionou com o THINNING_ZHANGSUEN, utilizando a minha figura!!

Comment: Que bom, fico feliz em ter ajudado, mas veja que isso não funciona em todos os casos, como eu disse na resposta deixe na cor branca somente o necessário para o thinning.

Comment: Mas essa função THINNING tem que ser trabalhada na imagem negativa, então usei o THRESH_BINARY_INV na imagem original. Após aplicar a função THINNING, tornei a inverter a imagem utilizando novamente o THRESH_BINARY_INV. Valeu pela dica, me poupou uma tonelada de código!